# FOSJsRouting Bundle

Tags: javascript, symfony

i have an error wir my Js Routing configuration.
I get "Uncaught Error: The route "pspiess_letsplay_customer_new" does not exist." in my console log.
I have installed the bundle via composer.
i have done all the 4. Steps

My Symfony version 2.3.21

My AppKernel

```
        $bundles = array(
        //.....
        new pspiess\LetsplayBundle\pspiessLetsplayBundle(),
        new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
        new Braincrafted\Bundle\BootstrapBundle\BraincraftedBootstrapBundle(),
        new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),
        new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),
        //.....
    );
```

My routing.yml

fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

pspiess_letsplay:
    resource: "@pspiessLetsplayBundle/Controller/"
    resource: "@pspiessLetsplayBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

My route

```
pspiess_letsplay_customer_new:
pattern:  /admin/customer/new
defaults: { _controller: pspiessLetsplayBundle:Customer:new }
```

My Action

```
    /**
 * Displays a form to create a new Customer entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="customer_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction() {
    $entity = new Customer();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

My Js Code

```
click: function() {
  console.log(Routing.generate('pspiess_letsplay_customer_new'));
```

}

My "router:debug" - all routes found with my route 
pspiess_letsplay_booking_new      ANY    ANY    ANY  /admin/booking/new

My "fos:js-routing:debug" - no route found

I think there is something wrong wirth my routing configuration, but i dont know what.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arent you missing the expose option in your routing ?

```
pspiess_letsplay_customer_new:
pattern:  /admin/customer/new
defaults: { _controller: pspiessLetsplayBundle:Customer:new }
options:
    expose: true
```

Comment: Thanks, your right. But why is this necessary? Now i dont have a error anymore, wich is great. But nothing happens. My controller is not triggering, do you have an idea why. This route work /web/app_dev.php/admin/customer/new

Comment: well it is necessary because you dont want to expose all your routes to everybody, think of internal admin and delete-trigger routes or whatever

Comment: also you have to request the route, Routing.generate('pspiess_letsplay_customer_new') will only generate a link, it wont request it , also `fos:js-routing:debug` should now be printing your route

Comment: Thank you, so at this point i have to do a href to my other page. window.location.href = Routing.generate('pspiess_letsplay_customer_new')